# Why is my startup script for azure web role got stuck?

Tags: com, startup, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to deploy my asp.net app to azure cloud service in web role. My app references a third party legacy component (32bit) which has caused me big headache. Since I only need one dll from this component, I spent a lot of time trying to figure out its dependencies, but no luck. It looks installing the component is the only choice for me, and it works if I manually install the component on the VM. Now, I'm trying to put it into startup script of web role. Here is some code:

ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

Startup.cmd:

```
ECHO Start: %date% %time% >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

ECHO Enabling 32 bit app on win64 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

ECHO Installing NET 3.5 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

IF EXIST "%RoleRoot%\Foundation_Installed.txt" (
ECHO Foundation is already installed. Exiting. >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
GOTO AfterAppInstall
)

ECHO Start installing Foundation at: %date% %time% >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
InstallFoundation.exe >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
ECHO Finished installing Foundation at: %date% %time% >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  REM   The application installed without error. Create a file to indicate that the application 
  REM   does not need to be installed again.

  ECHO This line will create a file to indicate that Foundation installed correctly. > "%RoleRoot%\Foundation_Installed.txt"
  ECHO Restarting virtual machine.
  powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "Restart-AzureVM -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -Name $vmname" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

) ELSE (
  REM   An error occurred. Log the error and exit with the error code.

  DATE /T >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
  TIME /T >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
  ECHO  An error occurred installing Foundation. Errorlevel = %ERRORLEVEL%. >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

  EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
)

:AfterAppInstall

ECHO End: %date% %time% >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
EXIT /B 0
```

StartupLog.txt, the log file on VM looks like this:

```
Start: Tue 05/06/2014  3:04:04.36 
Enabling 32 bit app on win64 
Applied configuration changes to section "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
Installing NET 3.5 

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result                           
------- -------------- ---------      --------------                           
True    No             NoChangeNeeded {}                                       


Start installing Foundation at: Tue 05/06/2014  3:04:10.96
```

So, it got stuck in running InstallFoundation. The deployment in cloud service is successful, but the instance got stuck with status

> Busy (Waiting for role to start... Application startup tasks are
>   running. [2014-05-06T03:04:04Z])

The InstallFoundation.exe was created using AutoIT to run installation silently. On VM command window, I could run it successfully and it ends the installation gracefully.

So, how does it get stuck there? Did I miss some privilege setting? What are the differences between command window and web role startup task?

Comment: May it be that it prompts for input?

Comment: Well, in command window, InstallFoundation.exe runs automatically without waiting for any input.

Comment: That's in command window but what happen on Azure?

Comment: That was exactly my question. I now suspect the "silent" install using AutoIT may not work for web role startup task at all, because it's using active window to delegate the progress, e.g. WinWaitActive("Thermo Foundation 3.0 - InstallShield Wizard", "&Next >").